# lightning:buttonIcon not showing the icon (iconName) in Winter 18

Tags: winter18, lightning-buttonicon

The code snippet below is directly out of the Dreamhouse app's MapCard component. It's supposed to show the close icon (X) at the top right conner of the dialog box. It works like a charm when it is executed under Summer 17 but not in Winter 18. Does anybody have any insight into this issue?

```
<div class="slds-modal__header">
    <lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-modal__close" variant="border-filled" onclick="{!c.closeDialog}" size="large" iconName="utility:close" />
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry this is my first post and for some reason the code snippet did not show up in the original message. Here's another attempt.

Comment: <div class="slds-modal__header">
                     <lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-modal__close" variant="border-filled" onclick="{!c.closeDialog}" size="large" iconName="utility:close" />
</div>

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! To format code, use the Format Code button, or press Ctrl-K/Cmd-K on your keyboard to format the code properly. I've fixed it for you this time. You can read the help topic on other things you can do, like *italics*, **bold**, and more, by clicking on the `?` icon in the question/answer editor.

Comment: I am seeing this same issue in Winter '18. The console output shows "Icon category "utility" does not map to a known icon asset. Make sure you are using a valid icon name"

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I looked at the dreamhouse git,

https://github.com/dreamhouseapp/dreamhouse-sfdx/blob/master/force-app/main/default/aura/MapCard/MapCard.cmp

The app has CSS which is modified/custom built in the style component to accommodate the developer needs

eg:slds_modal__close

If you want to purely copy paste, I will not recommend it without understanding what a CSS does. Let me explain what is happening here when you copy their CSS from the app

I took your code for the component

I copy pasted the CSS from the app

```
.THIS .slds-modal__close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 5%;
}
```

When you look at it first time you will assume the button is not rendering, but  the button renders at the corner of the screen.

[image]

> Personal suggestion : Take out all the class attributes you have in
>   your code Rework your way up by adding classes and position the button
>   as required.The component is working as expected

You are missing required value "alternativeText,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_buttonIcon.htm?search_text=lightning:buttonIcon

Also

> Usage Considerations When using lightning:buttonIcon in a standalone
>   app, extend force:slds to resolve the icon resources correctly

try this

```
    <lightning:buttonIcon  alternativeText="Close window." variant="border-filled" onclick="{!c.closeDialog}" size="large" iconName="utility:close" />
```

removed class attribute as pointed out by @sfdcfox

Comment: Just tried that, and BTW, one of those classes is also causing the button to break. Removing the class attribute seems to clear things up.

Comment: Thanks Rao and sfdcfox for your suggestions. I did tried both of your suggestions but still it did not.

Comment: @ha Doan can you please clearly show what errors you are seeing? It is jard to guess what you are facing

Comment: @Rao Here's the JavaScript error message. I hope it helps.
 /components/one-tmp-primitive-icon.js:3 <one-tmp-primitive-icon> Icon category "utility" does not map to a known icon asset. Make sure you are using a valid icon name.
getDefaultAssetPath @ /components/one-tmp-primitive-icon.js:3

Comment: are you on Lightning environment ? can you post your updated component with the fix suggested in the answer?

Comment: @Rao, since I can't get the Ctrl+k to work as suggested by sfdcfox, I am going to post the script in patches and you will need to put them back together. Also, note that class removal suggestions by sfdcfox did not work for me. Having said that, you can try to download Dreamhouse and test it out for yourself. I will send you the steps to reproduce.

Comment: @Rao here's my first batch:
    <lightning:card >
        <aura:set attribute="title">
            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:checkin" size="small" />
            <span class="title">{!v.title}</span>
        </aura:set>
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:buttonIcon onclick="{!c.fullScreen}" size="large" iconName="utility:expand" />
        </aura:set>

Comment: @Rao here's my 2nd batch:        
        <c:Map aura:id="map"/>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.fullScreen==true}">
            <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <c:Map aura:id="bigMap" />
                </div>

Comment: @Rao here's my 3rd batch
                <div class="btn slds-modal__close close x-large">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon alternativeText="Close Window" variant="border-filled" onclick="{!c.closeDialog}" size="large" iconName="utility:close" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>
        </aura:if>
    </lightning:card>

Comment: Here are the steps that you can follow to reproduce this issue. Note that this issue only surfaced on Winter 18 platform.
    1. Following this link to install the  Dreamhouse App, note thre are 2 links on step 4, select the second one: http://www.dreamhouseapp.io/installation/
    2. Make sure you follow the instruction to import the data.

Comment: @Rao 4. You will see a Leaflet Map on the right hand side. Click on the Expand button. 
5. You should see the same map enlarged on a modal screen. 
6. Note that there's no icon on the right hand corner where there should be a close icon (X).

Comment: 7. To see the underlying code for this component, go to Developer Console.
8. Open the c:MapCard component, the <lightning:buttonIcon> tag can be found between the <aura:if> tag toward the bottom of the markup page.
9. Note that the iconName is set to "utility:close" which is a legit tag as I did check the lightningsystemdesign library.

Comment: @Rao, thanks for your patience and for putting up with my clumsy postings. I will figure out how to format the comments properly in due time, hopefully. Again your help is greatly appreciated.